# Search keyword in line and print the line and the following line

Tags: c#

I am using the following approach to parse a text file and write the line that contains a specific keyword:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Downloads/apple.txt"))
        {
            string appleLine;
            bool lastLine = false;
            // currentLine will be null when the StreamReader reaches the end of file
            while ((appleLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Search, case insensitive, if the currentLine contains the searched keyword
                if (appleLine.IndexOf("Apple", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 || lastLine)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(appleLine);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Downloads\parsed.txt", true))
                    {
                        file.WriteLine(appleLine);
                        file.WriteLine();
                    }
                    lastLine = true;
                }

                if (lastLine)
                {
                    lastLine = false;
                }
            }
```

In apple.txt I have something like this:

--- Line1 Apple MacBook Pro ---

--- Line2 www.newegg.com ---

But this does not print out the line with the URL (Line 2). The apple.txt file could have something like 200 Lines.

Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a boolean that shows you found something to print and need to print the next line too. for example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool nextLineToPrint = false;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:/temp/ESMDLOG.csv"))
        {
            string currentLine;
            // currentLine will be null when the StreamReader reaches the end of file
            while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (nextLineToPrint)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(currentLine);
                    nextLineToPrint = false;
                }
                // Search, case insensitive, if the currentLine contains the searched keyword
                if (currentLine.IndexOf("I/RPTGEN", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(currentLine);
                    nextLineToPrint = true;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a boolean that indicates if the 'currentline' has been printed, then break out of the loop after the next line is printed. This way not only the currentLine will be printed, but also the next line, after which the while-loop will be exited.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:/temp/ESMDLOG.csv"))
{
    string currentLine;
    **bool lastline = false;**

    // currentLine will be null when the StreamReader reaches the end of file
    while((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Search, case insensitive, if the currentLine contains the searched keyword
        if(currentLine.IndexOf("I/RPTGEN", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 **|| lastline**)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(currentLine);
             lastline = true;
        }

        **//Optional, could also say lastline = false inside if, in case you want to keep looping after printing**
        **if(lastline){
              break;
        }**
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I would like to make. And it should loop after printing the the currentLine and lastLine. Anyway I did not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Without a more precise problem statement, it's impossible to know for sure what output you want. But something like the following will meet the goal as constrained so far:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:/temp/ESMDLOG.csv"))
{
    bool printWindow = false;
    Queue<string> window = new Queue<string>();
    string currentLine;
    // currentLine will be null when the StreamReader reaches the end of file
    while((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        bool nextPrintWindow = false

        // Search, case insensitive, if the currentLine contains the searched keyword
        if(currentLine.IndexOf("I/RPTGEN", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
             nextPrintWindow = true;
        }

        if (window.Count >= 3)
        {
            window.Dequeue();
        }

        window.Enqueue(currentLine);

        if (printWindow)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, window));
        }

        printWindow = nextPrintWindow;
    }
}
```

*(Warning: browser-only code above. Please forgive typos and other oversights.)*

The above maintains a `window` collection, i.e. a three-line "window" of the text in the file, by enqueuing the current line, and dequeuing the oldest line if the collection reaches a count of three elements.

At the same time, it maintains a flag that indicates whether to print the contents of the window after reading the next line. If this flag is set to `true`, it concatenates the lines in the `window` collection with newline characters and prints the whole thing out.

In this way, the current line along with the previous and next lines are all printed out if the current line meets your match criteria.

Note that the above will print three-line windows for every match. Lines may be printed more than once (as part of different three-line groups) if, for example, consecutive lines meet the match criteria. An alternative implementation would allow the window to grow beyond three elements if consecutive lines meet the match criteria, printing (and restarting) the window only once a line that doesn't meet the match criteria has been read.

Yet another alternative would require *two* non-matching lines before printing the window, i.e. if you want to make sure that even the non-matching lines are only ever printed once.

I leave those variation as an exercise for the reader. They would not be a lot different from the above, just minor changes in the maintenance of the window and management of the implied state machine encapsulated in the flag variables.

Comment: You've completely changed the question. You are no longer asking to print the line before, after, and including the line you found. If you really want to ask a different question, please post that as a new question instead of changing an existing question. If you don't want to ask a new question, then don't change the question. Either way, please roll back your edit so that your original question remains. Note that changing the question invalidates existing answers and wastes everyone's time.